# Writing a hangman program in python 3

Tags: python, string, algorithm

I'm trying to get a hangman program assignment to work. So the whole point of this game is to first get the player to choose a word and then the user keeps inputting letters to get the word. The game ends when the user makes 6 mistakes or guesses the right word. So this is how the program is supposed to go:

```
Please enter an integer number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: 1
```

From the output we see that the list has 10 words on it and that the user chosen the word with index one, which is horse.

The computer now prints the length of the chosen word as a hint to the user:

```
The length of the word is: 5
```

This is followed by a prompt asking for the first guess:

```
Please enter the letter you guess: t
```

As a response to a guess, the computer prints out the letters matched so far, whether the guess was correct (the letter was found in the mystery word), and, if the guess was incorrect, the “Hangman” graphic is shown. Since the letter "t" is not found in the word "horse", in this case the following output is shown:

```
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: _____
------------------
```

Here, the third line shows the first line of the "Hangman" graphic. This graphic will "grow" as the user makes more mistakes. If the user made fewer than 6 mistakes so far, the computer returns to asking for the next guess. In our example, the number of mistakes so far is one, so the computer returns to prompting for the next guess.
Assume that the next letter the user enters is "e":

```
Please enter the letter you guess: e
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
```

In this case, the letter was found (it is the last letter of the word "horse"). The match is indicated as shown in the third line. Here, "*_*_e" has 4 underscore characters, corresponding to the first four yet unmatched characters of "horse", which is followed by "e", the single character that was matched so far.
The interaction then repeats. As an example, consider the case when the user made only incorrect guesses and did not find out any more characters of "horse". The complete output would then be as follows:

```
Please enter the letter you guess: u
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
------------
| |

Please enter the letter you guess: a
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
------------
| |
| O

Please enter the letter you guess: i
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
------------
| |
| O
| / |

Please enter the letter you guess: d
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
------------
| |
| O
| / |
| |

Please enter the letter you guess: b
The letter is not in the word.
Letters matched so far: ____e
------------
| |
| O
| / |
| |
| / |
|
|

Too many incorrect guesses. You lost!
The word was: horse.
Goodbye!
```

Now consider when the player guesses the right letter

```
Please enter the letter you guess: o
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far: _o__e


Please enter the letter you guess: r
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far: _or_e


Please enter the letter you guess: h
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far: hor_e


Please enter the letter you guess: s
The letter is in the word.
Letters matched so far: horse

You have found the mystery word. You win!
Goodbye!
```

THIS IS WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

```
words = ['hello', 'horse', 'bye', 'moose', 'earth']    

#Choosing word
choose=input('Please enter an integer number 0<=number<10 to choose the word: ')
#check validity of guess
notValid=checkValidity(guess)

secret=words[int(choose)]
#print length of word
lenword=len(secret)
print('The length of the word is %i' %lenword)

while notValid==False:
    mistake=0

    while mistake<6:
        guess=input('Please enter the letter you guess: ')
        for letter in secret:
            if guess == letter:
                print('The letter is in the word.')
        else:
            print('The letter is not in the word.')
            mistake+=1
```

So my problem is that I can't figure out how to get the underscores and letters at the right positions in the print statement. How would I do this? Also how would I draw the hangman? If you need more clarification just ask. Thanks.

P.S. don't mind the notvalid stuff. that's just to check if number entered to choose the word is valid. For now i'm assuming it is.

Comment: If you will notice, there are *many* other hangman questions for Python, you can start there to look for answers, this question is undoubtedly a duplicate of some of them in some form or another. My suggestion is to see what others are doing to solve this. Good effort on the question, but you should have checked the site for an answer before you posted your question, I believe you will find one.

Comment: yea i did check first. there was one question like that but it was left unanswered b/c the question apparently wasn't clear. so i thought i should start a new question with a better explanation of what the problem was.

Comment: If you use python 2.x, You better use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` since `input()` is *evil* in python 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the underscores, you could remember which letters were already guessed, maybe in a set.

Then you could do

```
print(" ".join(letter if letter in found else '_' for letter in word))
```

And how to draw the hangman? I would put that into a function:

```
def draw_man(level):
    parts=['------------', '| |', '| O', '| / |', '| |', '| / |', '|', '|']
    for line in parts[:level]:
        print(line)
    return level <= len(parts) # This return value indicates if we have reached the limit (lost) or not (yet).
```